I want to reduce the space after a figure
Okay, this is probably gonna be a bit long, but it's because it's a pretty specific problem the one which I'm trying to tackle.
When I write a figure, I always make the caption span less than it is regularly made to span by LaTeX, i.e., I make it 0.8 times the line width. In order to achieve this I use a minipage environment. I've recently added the parskip package in order to augment the distance in between paragraphs (because I don't like how little space LaTeX has for that). Since I've used the pack, whenever I figure like I've always done, there seems to be a bunch of space between the end of the caption and the following line. I'll attach the MWE that displays this behaviour:
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx, caption, float}
\usepackage[skip=10pt]{parskip}

\begin{document}

Hello world.

I add the parskip package in order to achieve the distance between "Hello world" line and this one.
    
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{insert_image_here.png}
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
        \captionof{figure}{This is crazy nuts man.}
        \label{figT7:label}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

But it "overachieves" with this one.
    
\end{document} 


You need to examine the correctness of your view of the influence of the parskip package. If you delete the first paragraph to further simplify your test file, you'll quickly notice that the vertical gap between the caption line and the "But it overachieves with this one." line is indepedent of whether or not the parskip package is loaded.

@cfr - Actually, I did simplify the OP's code the way I suggested in the comment, and that's why I suggested they review their assumptions.

@Mico that's funny, because it definitely makes a difference for me.

@Mico or how did you man 'the caption line'? because strictly speaking, that's true, since the extra space is part of the caption line. but I assumed you meant it made no visible difference. should read more carefully, I guess.

Let's first clear up two misconceptions.

Loading the parskip package (with a non-zero value of the parskip option) does not affect the whitespace gap between text paragraphs and the position of an in-text float, i.e., a float with text both above and below it.
Instead, this whitespace gap is governed by a rubber length parameter named \intextsep. For the article document class, the default value of this parameter is 12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt if the main document font size is either 10pt or 11pt; it is 14pt plus 4pt minus 4pt if the main document font size is 12pt.

Encasing the \caption statement in a minipage also does not affect the whitespace gap below the figure environment.
In fact, I would recommend that you place both the graphic and the caption in a single minipage environment with a suitably-chosen width. This will assure that the caption text will not protrude to the left or right of the graphic.


So, what is going on to cause the appearance of an extra gap between the caption and the next text paragraph, relative to the gap that's placed above the graphic?

First, I recommend that you change \begin{figure}[H] to \begin{figure}[h]. Using the H placement option can cause lots of trouble and does very little that can be achieved with the h placement option.

Second, the caption "box" (yes, that's a TeXnical term) has a depth of about 1ex below the baseline. To eliminate this additional source of whitespace, you could issue the directive \vspace{-0.95ex} immediately after the \caption directive.


The following screenshot illustrates the situation in more detail. The thicker outer framelines are drawn because the showframe package has been loaded. The thinner "inner" horizontal lines, drawn by \hrule directives, serve to highlight the top and bottom of the space taken up by the figure environment.

If you look closely at the screenshot, you may note that there still appears to be more whitespace below the figure, including its caption, than above it. But that's merely a consequence of the fact that the text string
Using the \texttt{parskip} package doesn't achieve anything ...

doesn't contain many characters that have ascenders, i.e., parts that rise above the x-height line. If you were to replace this text string with, say,
ZZZZZ XXXXX ZZZZZ XXXXX ZZZZZ XXXXX ZZZZZ XXXXX

you'd notice that the apparent excess whitespace is gone completely.
A final observation: Since you're using a figure environment, I can see no reason for using a \captionof{figure}{...} directive. Please just use a regular \caption{...} directive instead.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
  %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi

\usepackage{showframe} % remove this instruction in real document
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[skip=10pt]{parskip} % comment out as needed

\begin{document}

I added the \texttt{parskip} package to increase the whitespace between paragraphs.
    
\begin{figure}[h!] % please don't use \begin{figure}[H]
\hrule % remove in real document
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{test} % use full available width
    \caption{This is a black box.}\label{figT7:label}    
    \vspace{-0.95ex} % <-- new
    \end{minipage}
\hrule % remove in real document
\end{figure}

Using the \texttt{parskip} package doesn't achieve anything special with this line.

\end{document} 


I really like this solution because it permits me to only change some things in the document while, @cfr solution will be good for new documents since the beginning. Thanks to both of you for helping out and for the clear up points you made at the start of your solution.

The reason you get extra space is the use of the minipage which add the paragraph spacing, I think. I would recommend instead using the margin option from caption, which you are already loading, to set additional indentations on each side for the captions. I've applied it only to figure but you could, of course, apply it to other float types or all of them.
Off-topic changes:

do not load inputenc if your input encoding is UTF8 as it is unnecessary if your TeX is even moderately recent;

" will give you incorrect quotation marks, at least for opening quotes:
  ``...''


dvipsnames was unused in your example; perhaps you need it in your real document, but not here;

consider using some element of glue in your skip value if your other skips are stretchy (as they are by default);

use standard images in examples others need to compile.


\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx, caption, float}
\usepackage[skip=10pt]{parskip}
\captionsetup[figure]{margin={.1\textwidth,.1\textwidth}}
\begin{document}

Hello world.

I add the parskip package in order to achieve the distance between "Hello world" line and this one.

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{cow}
  \captionof{figure}{This is crazy nuts man.}
  \label{figT7:label}
\end{figure}

But it ``overachieves'' with this one.

\end{document}


The spacing still doesn't look great to me, but it is not inserting any 'extra'.

One could also use \caption{...} not \captionof{figure}{....}.

@daleif indeed, I'd somehow failed to notice that.

\documentclass[10pt, twoside, dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[position=below,belowskip=0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt,aboveskip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage[skip=50pt]{parskip}

\intextsep = 0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt

\begin{document}

Hello world.

I add the parskip package in order to achieve the distance between "Hello world" line and this one.
    
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/sample/common/mill.png}%
\end{figure}

zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz 
    
\end{document} 

Regarding the above MWE:

\parskip has nothing to do with the space after a figure since it is set to a ridiculously large value.
LaTeX's float mechanism uses a dimension called \intextsep to put space before and after a figure. If you set that to zero, then you minimize the space before and after a figure.
There is still some extra space after the figure which I can't identify.
The spacing after the figure has nothing to do with ascenders.
The extra space after the figure has nothing to do with stretchable glue since plus 0pt minus 0pt is part of the \intextsep specification.
The caption itself has nothing to do with the extra space since that space is constant with or without a caption.


Welcome to TeX.SE.
